# Proguard error with parse

Tags: parse-platform, proguard

I built with parse 1.5.1 without problems when progurad only add one line.

```
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

I upgraded parse to 1.9.4 ,but parse didn't work.
 I reference others topics and I added below lines still didn't work.
 I can ignore the parse warning,but it can't solve any problems.

```
-keepattributes Annotation,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Signature

-keep interface com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
```

I got error when I built the release version with Parse 1.9.4.

```
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find referenced class okio.BufferedSink
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Warning: there were 72 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-08-13 10:49:29 - wargame] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had these issue myself so I asked parse for help. They came up with the following proguard file:

```
# Keep source file names, line numbers, and Parse class/method names for easier debugging
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepnames class com.parse.** { *; }

# Required for Parse
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: It works,but i have found it was google play service problem.